# How to retrieve user data extended from IdentityUser?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity

I extended IdentityUser and I need to select logged in user with his all data.
I can get current logged in user but on run time I get error null reference exception !!

briefly, I need to get the user "teacher" with all his lessons, Messages, and Assignments.
Currently, I get all Lessons successfully but I can't get the user himself. and It gives the following error.

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.

My whole code like the following

**The Model** AppUser Extends IdentityUser

```
public class AppUser: IdentityUser
{
    [Key]
    public override string Id { get => base.Id; set => base.Id = value; }
    [EmailAddress]
    public override string Email { get => base.Email; set => base.Email = value; }
    public override string PhoneNumber { get => base.PhoneNumber; set => base.PhoneNumber = value; }
    public override string UserName { get => base.UserName; set => base.UserName = value; }

    public string Name { get; set; }        // extention 
    public string Photo { get; set; }       // extention 
    public string Description { get; set; } // extention 
}
```

**View Model** TeachersVM

```
public class TeachersVM
{
    private AppDbContext _context;

    public TeachersVM(AppDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public string UserID { get; set; }

    public AppUser appUser { get; set; }
    //public List<Lesson> lessons { get; set; }
    //public List<Message> messages { get; set; }
    //public List<Assignment> assignments { get; set; }

    public TeachersVM Init(string userId) // take user Id and return this view model itself
    {
        // in trace time userId has value but it returns appUser null
        appUser = _context.appUser.Where(l => l.Id == userId).FirstOrDefault();

        lessons = _context.lesson.Where(l => l.TechID == userId).ToList(); // this one works well
        //messages = _context.message.Where(l => l.TechID == userId).ToList();
        //assignments = _context.assignment.Where(l => l.TechID == userId).ToList();
        return this;
    }
}
```

In **The Controller** this is how I call the View Model teachersVM

```
// Using trace I can read user base data. however, extended data are not visible 
IdentityUser user = await userManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.Email);
// teachersVM injected in the constructor 
return View("TchrProfile", teachersVM.Init(user.Id)); 
// this takes user Id and returns teachersVM which include all lessons, messages and assignments for specific user (I can't even get the user)
```

**the view**

```
   <partial name="_MyLessons" model="Model.lessons" /> // lessons comes with data very well
   <partial name="_MyData" model="Model.appUser" />  // however, appUser return null !!! why !?
   @*<partial name="_MyAssignment" model="Model.assignments" />
   <partial name="_MyMessage" model="Model.messages" />*@
```

in **Startup** I use TeachersVM as a service

```
    services.AddTransient<TeachersVM>();
```

**AppDbContext**

```
public class AppDbContext : IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser>
{
    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {

    }

    public DbSet<Lesson> lesson { get; set; } 
    public DbSet<Message> message { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Assignment> assignment { get; set; }
    public DbSet<AppUser> appUser { get; set; } // <-----
}
```

Again ...
In the controller, I can find user base data of base class IdentityUser but I can't retrieve extended data !
In the view model, I can find userId but I can't retrieve data from _context.appUser !

All I need to get the current user with all his data including his extended data not just base data.
what do you think might be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. it was in two places.

First in **Startup**

```
        services.AddIdentity<AppUser, IdentityRole>(
            //options => { options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true; }
        )
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
        //instead of -------------------------------------------
        //services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
        //.AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>();
```

Second in **Controller constructor**

```
    private readonly UserManager<AppUser> userManager;
    private readonly SignInManager<AppUser> signInManager;
    private RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager;
    private TeachersVM teachersVM;

    public AccountController(
        UserManager<AppUser> userManager, 
        SignInManager<AppUser> signInManager, 
        RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager,
        TeachersVM teachersVM)
    {
        this.userManager = userManager;
        this.signInManager = signInManager;
        this.roleManager = roleManager;
        this.teachersVM = teachersVM;
    }

    // UserManager<AppUser> and SignInManager<AppUser>
    // rather than 
    // UserManager<IdentityUser> and SignInManager<IdentityUser>
```

then, I don't need this in AppDbContext

```
     public DbSet<AppUser> appUser { get; set; }
```

and also I have to change this in AppDbContext

```
     : IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser>
```

to this

```
     : IdentityDbContext<AppUser>
```